# difference betweeen regedit services and services.msc services list?

Tags: windows-services

recently i have seen the registry for get the services information. during that i have seen a lot of services in that list(HKLM\currentcontrolset\services) when compared with the services.msc services list.

1) why regedit(registry) shows more services than services.msc list? please help me to clear on this?

2) is it shows both driver services and win32 services? because i also got to know services are in two types. one is device driver services and system services.

if possible please give me examples for devicedriver services and where can we see in windows os.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found that services.msc contains only win32 services. the regedit(registry ) contains both driver services and win32 services.

Answer (score 0):

1) Good question, there is different type of services, Kernel device driver, File System Driver, Win32Service , Win32Program ... Services.msc show Win32 Services because you shouldn't alter other type of services.

Check this link for diff: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101501

Check this link for querying all kind for services: https://servicespp.codeplex.com/

Thanks